# How can i align textview like in the image below for all screen

Tags: android

I have to align text on the different dots in the given image for all screens . Is there anyone who can help me in achieving this?

[image]

Comment: How about making the thread straight? Then you can put your own circles and textViews along it. And even thread can be made using android xml rather than using an image?

Comment: Vipul sir  i have to make the  same look i mean i cant make a thread straight then what i have to do.

Comment: create multiple images with each step and change at runtime. One of solution

Comment: I have to open a new view too on click of a textview in this @virendrao sir.

Comment: As far as I know, this exact prototype is not possible to achieve using android xml attributes. Yes you can use approximation and position the elements relative to middle of the screen but then Android have different screen sizes. Image will be repositioned and everything will mess up. The solution provided by @virendrao is plausible, but I guess you need to click on these textViews, right? That will make it more difficult when using different images.

Comment: then above solution wont work..did you try any code using RelativeLayout will be good option

Comment: If you still have to do it exactly like this and using android XML, I can think of relativeLayout or TableLayout being strong contenders. I don't think you'll be able to achieve this exact layout, but you can try to be as close as possible. If I were to advise, I would advise using an XML coded thread and circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite hard to use `XML` markup to implement your UI but there are `Canvas` methods which easily draw all your primitives.

Sample:

```
private Paint circlePaint;
private Paint linePaint;
private Paint textPaint;
private String[] titles;
private float circleRadius;

@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    float height = getHeight();
    float width = getWidth();
    float circleX;//set initial X depending on width and height of screen
    float circleY;//set initial Y

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        String title = titles[i];
        canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, circleRadius, circlePaint);
        canvas.drawText(title, circleX + circleRadius, circleY, textPaint);

        float nextCircleX;//calculate next X coordinate
        float nextCircleY;//calculate next Y coordinate

        canvas.drawLine(circleX, circleY, nextCircleX, nextCircleY, circlePaint);

        circleX = nextCircleX;
        circleY = nextCircleY;
    }
}
```